# How to find the longest path between certain kind of relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, path-finding, java

I have a graph database in neo4j,there is two kinds of relationship between nodes:{INCLUDE,USED},I want to find the longest path among the "USED" relationships,the relationships are not serialized,they can be apart from each other.

can you please help me to write it in java api,embedded database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try both.  Show your workings.

Comment: I wrote a query in cypher,but it takes long to give results from a java application,but I don not know how to write in java api,maybe i have to add it to my question.

Comment: Call cypher queries from embedded should be fast, so I guess your query might not be efficient. Share it and then we may be able to help.